# Confluence migration from cloud to server

Tags: confluence, confluence-macros

We have migrated a space from cloud instance to server instance,in cloud instance we were using "Plantuml diagrams for confluence" but in server we are using "Confluence PlantUML Plugin" .so macro name are different in both cloud and server ,so macro name for cloud is "plantumlcloud" but for server it is "plantuml".so ,in pages after migration it is showing "plantumlcloud" not a valid macro ,kindly help to resolve.

Comment: "PlantUML Diagrams for Confluence" has a server version: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215115/plantuml-diagrams-for-confluence?hosting=server&tab=overview Perhaps your migration would work if you use the same add-on in both.

Comment: (Also I don't see "Confluence PlantUML Plugin" on Marketplace -- what is that exactly?)

Answer (score 0):

In general, migration of confluence spaces to another application which is not running the same plugins will cause any functionality of that plugin to break.

If you migrate hosting platforms, and have the equivalent version of the plugin for your new platform, created by the same developer, in most cases you will retain functionality, however there will often be differences between versions.

These differences are found especially when downgrading, and moving from cloud to server is a very definite example of a downgrade, as cloud will always run the latest version.

In general I would reccomend against a migration from cloud to server, and when it must be done, time should be spent to ensure compatability with all plugins, and migration guides and plans should be made and followed.

As commented by @tgdavies, there seems to be an equivelent version of the plugin you were using on cloud, so hopefully that can resolve your issue.